# Angular 2 SpaTemplate Node seems to not be working

Tags: angularjs, node.js, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I am trying to follow a guide posted on Youtube by Microsoft, although my luck just isn't working out. The first time I attempted to follow the guide I installed a newer version of node and my computer freaked out and I ultimately had to do a complete wipe. Now that I am back online I was hoping to follow the guide from a clean computer.

Video Link: [Youtube Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6rTTqeFlC44)

I went ahead and downloaded the same version of node that is shown in the video.

**EDIT** - Don't ask me how or why, because nothing internally has changed, but I attempted this again and it worked perfectly fine.

Firstly I can follow the video and get the template downloaded. However around, 6:37 in the video. The npm install runs for a long time and that towards the end I start getting a load of errors.

Secondly, after getting all these errors I decided to try and open my visual studio project anyway. Once open it acknowledges that my project is missing dependencies. Also the behavior is different then the videos, pressing ctrl+f5 does start my debug session, however my debug session launches a console window.

The log says try running this command as an administrator, I did that. I am very new to node.js and super new to asp.net core.

Error log file from npm install - [Paste Bin](http://pastebin.com/6YMBgW6w)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to start with the Angular template is to go with asp.net core 2.0, where you have Angular template available in Visual Studio 2017.
[Angular Template in VS2017](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FVNoL.png)
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2017/08/14/announcing-asp-net-core-2-0/